# Identify $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

I need help with this problem:

Define a equivalent relation in $\mathbb{R}$:

1-identifying $x$ with itself if $x \notin \mathbb{N}$

2-$1,2,3,...$ belongs to the same equivalent class (I am asuming that $\mathbb{N} =\{1,2,...\}$).

Let's call $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}$ the set of equivalent classes under the relation defined above.  Also I can give the quotient topology to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}$. There is a geometric way to picture this topology set?

Thank you

Comment: You can imagine $\mathbb{R}$ as being the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then take the point $(0,1)$ and draw a line from it to each point of $\mathbb{N}$.  Your $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}$ is topologically equivalent to that.  By shrinking the added lines, it becomes a wedge of circles.

Comment: beautiful!  thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $X_2=\mathbb{R}/ \{1,2\}$: it can be imagined as two step construction:

1. $((-\infty,1]\cup [2,\infty))/\{1,2\}$ - it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.
2. $[1,2]/\{1,2\}$ is homeomorphic to circle $\mathbb{S}_1$.

Gluing those two up gives real line tangent to circle. This is $X_2$.
Going up in $k=3,4,...$ will add to $X_k$ another circle that meets all other and the line in one point. This means that $X_{\omega}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{N}$ is ray $(-\infty,1]$ glued up with countably many circles at one point.

Comment: This is a good picture. But a word of caution: We can construct this in $\mathbb R^2$ but the quotient  topology is NOT the subspace topology as a subspace of  $\mathbb R^2$ (with the usual topology on $\mathbb R^2$).  In $\mathbb R/\mathbb N ,$  the  point (the equivalence class) $\mathbb N$ is a point with uncountable character.